# how to get facebook news feed on android with phonegap?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've been playing with phonegap's android facebook plugin. The hackbook example did not specify how to get news feed for a user from facebook. Is there an API for doing this? I've done extensive search in stackoverflow but did not get any answers.
https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Comment: See the `home` or `feed` connection of the [`User` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Answer (score 2):

The API endpoint for the user's news feed is `me/home`.  Make sure you have the extended permission `read_stream`.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fhome

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the plugin for authentication, then the normal [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for your requests?

Comment: The plugin is actually javascript. However, I just don't see how to get news feed using Graph API, neither from your link.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question. It looks like `https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=` is the closest to the newsfeed, but Facebook acknowledges that this contains different stories than they user would see on Facebook.com